# getting comma separated string in a column for a large number of comma separated values efficiently in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table which likes this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33m67.jpg)[sql table image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33m67.jpg)

I am currently using the following query to get a single comma separated value :

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL  SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) numbers INNER JOIN mytable
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1 where SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) = 'm';
```

I was wondering if there is a better way I could do this as it does not work well for large number of comma separated values as I am using `SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2` and so on to get more than one comma separated value

Comment: Why do you have the values in a comma separated list and not in a new table by using a 3NF table layout?

Comment: This is actually part of a form where I enter the data separated by a comma . Hence the data gets saved in the column separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. Convert your tables and data to a 3NF table layout. This way it is much easier to write queries for your database.